# Bash, how to extract grep occurences and store them in an array

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a grep operation that yields the following:

`VRHFIN =Ce : [core=Xe4] s2d1f1
VRHFIN =O: s2p4
VRHFIN =C: s2p2
VRHFIN =H: ultrasoft test`

The objective is to extract the part after the equal sign (which indicates a chemical element) and before the colon, and push them into an array in the order of appearance. In this specific case the desired array would contain

`Ce O C H`

How can this be achieved using regular expressions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution using GNU grep

Let's take this as the test file:

```
$ cat file
VRHFIN =Ce : [core=Xe4] s2d1f1
VRHFIN =O: s2p4
VRHFIN =C: s2p2
VRHFIN =H: ultrasoft test
other irrelevant lines
here.
```

If you have GNU `grep`, which is what you have if you are running Linux, then you can extract the names of elements like this:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<==)\w+(?= *:)' file
Ce
O
C
H
```

You can put those names into a bash array as follows:

```
elements=($(grep -oP '(?<==)\w+(?= *:)' file))
```

The `-P` option tells GNU grep to use Perl-style regular expressions.  `(?<==)` requires a `=` before the match and `(?= *:)` requires a colon after match.

We can verify that the array is correct via the `declare` command:

```
$ declare -p elements
declare -a elements='([0]="Ce" [1]="O" [2]="C" [3]="H")'
```

#### Solution not requiring GNU grep

One can obtain the same effect using `sed`:

```
$ sed -nE 's/.*=([[:alpha:]]+)[[:space:]]*:.*/\1/p' file
Ce
O
C
H
```

The results can be stored in a bash array just like before:

```
$ elements2=($(sed -nE 's/.*=([[:alpha:]]+)[[:space:]]*:.*/\1/p' file))
$ declare -p elements2
declare -a elements2='([0]="Ce" [1]="O" [2]="C" [3]="H")'
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution from GNU grep worked pretty well

Answer (score 1):

You can use process substitution to extract values from grep output and store them in array:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=()

while IFS=':= ' read -r _ b _; do
   arr+=("$b")
done < <(grep 'pattern' file)

# print array
declare -p arr
# or else
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

Replace `grep 'pattern' file` with your actual `grep` command.

Answer (score 1):

Nice and simple:

```
aArray=($(sed -n "s/^\w*\s*=\(\w*\)\s*.*/\1/p" /path/filename))
```

- aArray=() - identifies contents as elements of an array
- $()       - runs contents as command
- sed -n    - do not print
- s/        - substitute
- ^         - beginning of line
- \w*       - zero or more word characters
- \s*       - zero ore more whitespace characters
- \( \)   - store everything inside as \1
- .*        - match anything
- /\1       - replace everything with contents of \1
- p         - print results